# IE10 does not show the transparent DIV/waiting message

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, internet-explorer-10

Have a DIV container which acts as transparent background with loading message.

HTML code of the DIV conatainer

```
<div id="generatingexcel" style="display:none; position: fixed; width: 100%;height: 100%; z-index: 999; top: 0; left: 0; background:rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.5);">
    <div style="color: #fff; font-size: 24px; position: absolute; left: 500px; top: 400px;">
        <strong>Generating Excel Please wait....</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Executing an ajax call and first thing in ajax success function is to make the Transparent DIV display:block and once the execution is done will put back the display :none for Transparent DIV.

```
$("#generatingexcel").css("display", "block");

$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : url,
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function (msg) {
        //code
    },
    async : false,
    error : function (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});

$("#generatingexcel").css("display", "none");
```

It works fine in FF but for some reason in IE10 the transparent DIV and loading message does not show up.

So just to debug i added a alert() msg after the display block line then the transparent DIV with message is shown in IE10. once i remove the alert again it does not show up.

```
$("#generatingexcel").css("display", "block");
alert("Wait");
```

Why does not it get trigger or am i missing anything here.

Answer (score 0):

You cant add two conditions on same time. If you make that, only the last conditions is fired. you can too used `show()/hide()` methods for display none your element

**Solution 1**

```
$("#generatingexcel").show();

$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : url,
    async : false,
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function (msg) {
        $("#generatingexcel").hide();
    },
    error : function (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

**Solution 2**

You can add this to the `<head>` tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >
```

Solution found here : [Solution to IE10 Ajax Problem](http://code.gishan.me/code/solution-to-ie10-ajax-problem/)

**UPDATE**

Ok i dont know why the overlay not show with IE but i have found a solution.

Insert into a `setTimeout()` with duration 1. I have try with big and small Json data.

Please try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#generatingexcel").css("display", "block");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : url,
            cache: false,
            async : false,
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success : function (msg) {
                $("#generatingexcel").css("display", "none");
            },
            error : function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    },1)
})
```

Comment: Which conditions do you mean? His Ajax has `async : false` so the css is modified consecutively and the ajax is blocking.

Comment: I want say the second `$("#generatingexcel").css` after ajax() is called before the ajax call is succes.

Comment: Sry :( . Please create a jsfiddle or a link for check your issue